# Re-use agent in parallel stages of declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Declarative Pipelines 1.3.2 plugin and I want to use the same agent (as in only specifying the `agent` directive once) in multiple parallel stages:

```
stage('Parallel Deployment')
{
    agent { dockerfile { label 'docker'; filename 'Dockerfile'; } }
    parallel
    {
        stage('A') { steps { ... } } 
        stage('B') { steps { ... } }
    }
}
```

However, Jenkins complains:

> "agent" is not allowed in stage "Parallel Deployment" as it contains parallel stages

A solution is to duplicate the `agent` directive for each parallel stage, but this is tedious and leads to lot of duplicated code with many parallel stages:

```
stage('Parallel Deployment')
{
    parallel
    {
        stage('A') { 
            agent { dockerfile { label 'docker'; filename 'Dockerfile'; } }
            steps { ... } 
        } 
        stage('B') { 
            agent { dockerfile { label 'docker'; filename 'Dockerfile'; } }
            steps { ... } 
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more idiomatic solution, or is duplicating `agent` directive necessary for each of the parallel stages?

Comment: Are you not able to declare the agent at Pipeline level so all stages run on the same agent ?

Comment: You are totally correct; if this was the answer, I'd accept it now.

Comment: Added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Specifying the agent at `pipeline` level can be a solution, but has the potential downside that the agent is up & running for the whole duration of the build.
Also note that this means each stage (that doesn't define its own `agent`) is run on the same agent instance, not agent type. If the parallel processes are CPU / resource intensive, this might not be what you want.

Still, if you want to run parallel stages on one instance, and can't or want not to define the agent at `pipeline` level, here's a workaround for the declarative syntax:

```groovy
stage('Parallel Deployment') {
    agent { dockerfile { label 'docker'; filename 'Dockerfile'; } }
    stages {
        stage('A & B') {
            parallel {
                stage('A') { steps { ... } } 
                stage('B') { steps { ... } }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you go for a scripted pipeline, which doesn't have this limitation.

Answer (score -3):

Declare the agent at Pipeline level so all stages run on the same agent.

Comment: Can you clarify? @Sean Pianka wants the stages to run on identical agents, not the same agent. How can the Jenkinsfile be written to make the agent definition reusable?

Comment: I tried that and parallel stages did not run in parallel 